# QTextEdit (QT Control) alternative for MFC Application?

Tags: html, qt, mfc, controls, richedit

Do you know any (paid or free) MFC control with features like (QT) QTextEdit control?

- Good HTML (and may be RTF) support (import, export)
- Ability to edit manual control content

:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> MFC7 includes several new classes that encapsulate the Internet Explorer MSHTML editing control. This control is an ActiveX control that provides WYSIWYG editing and browsing, and the MFC and ATL wrappers for this class make it's use very straight forward.

[CHtmlEditCtrl Class (MFC) | msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h14ht0dh%28VS.71%29.aspx)

[Use CHtmlEditCtrl to Create a Simple HTML Editor | experts-exchange.com](http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/Programming/System/Windows__Programming/Use-CHtmlEditCtrl-to-Create-a-Simple-HTML-Editor.html)